# Your age and my age

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, time

This is not a very difficult problem, but it seems that it hasn't been asked here.
It's one of my favorites, so here we go:

> I am twice as old as you were when I was as old as you are.
>   When you will be as old as I am, the sum of our ages will be 81.
>   How old are we?

---

Edit: I totally misremembered the second sentence, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I am 36 years old, you are 27 years old.**

Proof:

Let's say I am $X$ years old and you are $Y$ years old. I am older than you by $(X-Y)$ years. Then when I was $Y$ you were $Y-(X-Y)$ years old. Therefore:

$X = 2 \cdot (Y-(X-Y)) = 4 \cdot Y-2 \cdot X$

or

$X = 4/3 \cdot Y$ (1)

When you will be X years old I will be $X+(X-Y)$ years old. Therefore:

$X+(X+(X-Y)) = 81$

or

$Y = 3 \cdot X-81$ (2)

From (1) and (2) we get:

$X = 4/3 \cdot (3 \cdot X-81) = 4 \cdot X-108$

So $X = 36$. $Y = 3/4 \cdot X = 27$.

Answer (score 6):

Solution from the perspective of the asker.

**The difference $x$.**

The first sentence gives us two equations:
$$\text{I}~~~~ inow=2 \cdot youthen$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
{\scriptsize ithen\overset{\text{as old as}}= younow} \\
{\scriptsize younow=inow-x}\\
{\scriptsize \implies ithen=inow-x} \\ 
{\scriptsize \implies ithen-x=inow-2x}\\
{\scriptsize  \text{and since}~~~~ youthen = ithen -x} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$\text{II}~~~~ youthen = inow - 2x$$
$$ \Rightarrow inow=2 \cdot (inow-2x) \\
\Rightarrow inow=4x $$

When you become as old as I am now, I will be x years older (2nd sentence):

$$2 \cdot inow+x=81$$ 
$$ inow=4x $$
$$ \Rightarrow x=9 $$

**Our ages.**

Now we know that
$$inow=36$$
$$inow-younow=9$$
$$ \Rightarrow younow =27$$